# Batch renaming of files according to a separate ID file

Tags: ubuntu, bash, rename

I am working with Ubuntu 16 and I have a directory with hundreds of files with unique filenames.

I would like to batch rename them according to a separate ID file.

For example:

Original directory

```
FileA.ext
FileB.ext
FileC.ext
IrrelevantFile.txt
etc
```

ID file

```
FileA.ext File1.ext
FileB.ext File2.ext
FileC.ext File3.ext
etc
```

Transformed directory

```
File1.ext
File2.ext
File3.ext
IrrelevantFile.txt
etc
```

Note that the original directory includes a file with a separate extension (`IrrelevantFile.txt`) that is not included in the ID file. Therefore the Bash script should rely strictly on the ID file and rename only the files that are present there.

Can you please help?

Comment: Just read the ID file and rename only files that are explicitly listed in that file? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: In cmd line `for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %A in ("ID.txt") Do if exist %A REn %A %B` in a batch double the precent signs.

Comment: @Seth My problem is that I am a newbie in Bash.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks a lot for the effort will give it a try!

Comment: That command is for windows cmd/batch use, not bash. Your tags are ambiguous.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks, how can I adjust it to bash?

Comment: @AntonisG You just need to click on the [edit](//superuser.com/posts/1337881/edit) link at the bottom of your question, just above the comments. (I've already done it for you this time ;-) )

Comment: I'm not that familiar with bash yet `while read from to junk; do   mv -- "$from" "$to"; done <"ID.txt"`